# How to return historical probability of rain given location and date

Tags: python, r, weather, meteostat

I am using rain as an intrumental variable, so I need to pull hisotry probablity of rain given location and time to each row.
Prefer python since I clean most of my data on python.

| County | State | Date | Rain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fulton | SC | 2019-1-1 | ? |
| Chatham | GA | 2017-9-3 | ? |

Probably looking for some python library and code to find the date and create the column.
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Hello there, welcome to SO. You could include your desired output and the code of your current attempts. 
Also, I do not really understand what you are planning to do. Do you have a dataset with the rain probabilities containing location, date and probablity elsewhere and you are looking to extract only a few observations? Or do you want to fetch information from an online database?
For the extraction of observations, consider using `dplyr::filter()` in r, for python i dont know.

Comment: This site is for problems with code, not to give you suggestions on code or packages to apply to your ideas. After you pick a language and try some code, if you have problems, you should take the tour and then post a question relevant to code in the problem. Please take the tour to get a better idea of how this site works: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is a probability in historical / observed datasets does not exist. The probability is derived from probabilistic weather forecasts. When the weather went through, you can say if there was rain or not, means 1 or 0.

But from a data science perspective there can be alternative to that. E.g. you can build up a similarity tree or an Analog Ensemble to determine probability for rain on certain weather patterns.
But you need more information about the weather and weather regime.
At the your information will be independent from the date. The probability information will be a function on the day of year  e.g.